# How to uninstall Software using c# by calling Software UninstallString Listed in Registry file of that Software  But the Process Is Not Working 

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a software that will list all the software install
in Computer 
now i want to Uninstall it using my Program In C# by 
calling the Uninstall Key of that software in 
Registry Key 
My Program Is
Like That  But the Process Is Not Working

```
var UninstallDir = "MsiExec.exe /I{F98C2FAC-6DFB-43AB-8B99-8F6907589021}";
string _path = "";
string _args = "";
Process _Process = new Process();
if (UninstallDir != null && UninstallDir != "")
{
    if (UninstallDir.StartsWith("rundll32.exe"))
    {
        _args = ConstructPath(UninstallDir);
        _Process.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory.ToString() + "\\explorer.exe";
        _Process.StartInfo.Arguments = Environment.SystemDirectory.ToString() + "\\" + UninstallDir;
        _Process.Start();
    }
    else if (UninstallDir.StartsWith("MsiExec.exe"))
    {
        _args = ConstructPath(UninstallDir);
        _Process.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory.ToString() + "\\cmd.exe";
        _Process.StartInfo.Arguments = Environment.SystemDirectory.ToString() + "\\" + UninstallDir;
        _Process.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        //string Path = ConstructPath(UninstallDir);
        _path = ConstructPath(UninstallDir);
        if (_path.Length > 0)
        {
            _Process.StartInfo.FileName = _path;
            _Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            _Process.Start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
    Process p = new Process(); 
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe"; 
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/x {F98C2FAC-6DFB-43AB-8B99-8F6907589021}/qn"; 
    p.Start();
```

Refer to this link: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/msiexec.mspx?mfr=true

HTH.

Comment: This is not enough to construct the path of : 
msiexec.exe /x {F98C2FAC-6DFB-43AB-8B99-8F6907589021}/qn

some time the format if  uninstallstring is
like: msiexec.exe /I {F98C2FAC-6DFB-43AB-8B99-8F6907589021}/qn

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `misexec.exe` code is that running `cmd.exe someprogram.exe` doesn't start the program because cmd.exe doesn't execute arguments passed to it. But, you can tell it to by using the /C switch as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands). In your case this should work:

```
    _Process.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory.ToString() + "\\cmd.exe";
    _Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + Environment.SystemDirectory.ToString() + "\\" + UninstallDir;
```

Where all I did was add `/C` (with a space after) to the beginning of the arguments. I don't know how to get your rundll32.exe code to work, however.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks good, but keep a space before `\qn`:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/x {F98C2FAC-6DFB-43AB-8B99-8F6907589021} /qn";
```

Otherwise it wont work in silent mode.